# Requiring unknown module "ReactInstanceHandles"

Tags: react-native

Recently updated to React 0.19.0 and have started to get this error.
I've tried cleaning out the gradle folders but I'm still getting the error.
I've also tried restarting the package manager.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by

1. `rm -rf node_modules`
2. Remove `react` from package.json, since react-native now includes it.
3. `npm install`